# Не отправляются данные в базу данных

Tags: php

Ребят помогите исправить проблему, данные инпута приходят на почту но не записываются в базу данных...
Какая может быть причина?`

```html
<!-- <input type='text' name="getportfolio"> -->


<?
if((isset($_POST['getportfolio'])&&$_POST['getportfolio']!="")){ //Проверка отправилось ли наше поля name и не пустые ли они
          // Переменные с формы
        $user_mail = $_POST['getportfolio'];     
        // Параметры для подключения
        $db_host = "localhost"; 
        $db_user = "root";
        $db_password = "";
        $db_table = "portfolio";  
        // Подключение к бд
        $db = mysql_connect($db_host,$db_user,$db_password) OR DIE("Не могу создать соединение ");     
        // Выборка базы
        mysql_select_db("mydb",$db);      
        // Установка кодировки соединения
        mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'",$db);      
        $result = mysql_query ("INSERT INTO ".$db_table." (user_mail) VALUES ('$user_mail')");     
        if ($result = 'true'){
            echo "Информация занесена в базу данных";
        }else{
            echo "Информация не занесена в базу данных";
        } 
        $to = 'blackgrow.dev@gmail.com'; //Почта получателя, через запятую можно указать сколько угодно адресов
        $subject = 'Запрос на Портфолио'; //Загаловок сообщения
        $message = '
                <html>
                    <head>
                        <title>'.$subject.'</title>
                    </head>
                    <body>
                    <div>
                    <div style="padding:30px 0;padding-left:30px;background-color:rgb(230, 241, 251);">Веб Студия Blackgrow, холим и лелеем!</div>
                        <div style="background-color:#F4FAFF;padding: 30px;">
                            <div>Здравствуй, admin!<br><br>
                            У вас имеются новые уведомления (+1):<br><br>
                            - Посетель Вашей Веб Студии запросил отправку Вашего портфолио - '.$_POST['getportfolio'].' ;
                            </div>   
                            <br><br><br>
                            <div style="text-align:center;">Пожалуйста, не забудьте отправить портфолио клиенту.</div>  
                        </div>
                    </div>                 
                    </body>
                </html>'; //Текст нащего сообщения можно использовать HTML теги
        $headers  = "Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8 \r\n"; //Кодировка письма
        $headers .= "From: Веб Студия Blackgrow <info@blackgrow.com>\r\n"; //Наименование и почта отправителя
        mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers); //Отправка письма с помощью функции mail
}
?>
```

`

Comment: Ошибки какие? Какую нибудь диагностику проводили?

Answer (score 0):

1)

```
if ($result = 'true'){
    echo "Информация занесена в базу данных";
}else{
    echo "Информация не занесена в базу данных";
}
```

Операция `$result = 'true'` является присваиванием переменной `$result` строки `true` и всегда на выходе будет давать истину (т.е. ветка `else` никогда не будет отрабатывать)

Тут должно быть так: `if ($result === true)`

2) Что у вас приходит вот сюда `$user_mail = $_POST['getportfolio'];`? Дальше по коду у вас эта переменная используется ТОЛЬКО в запросе и, если в ней какая-то чертовщина(например апострофы), то запрос может и не проходить.

3) Вставьте после строки с `$result = mysql_query (...` строку `echo mysql_error($db);` и посмотрите, что выведет.

4) НЕ ИСПОЛЬЗУЙТЕ РАСШИРЕНИЕ mysql!!!! Оно уже черт знает сколько времени не поддерживается, а в PHP7 вообще удалено. Используйте либо mysqli, либо PDO

Comment: Дополню `$result = mysql_query ("INSERT INTO ".$db_table." (\`user_mail\`) VALUES ('".$user_mail."')");`

Comment: сюда приходит только валидный емеил

Comment: вот так правильно? $result = mysqli_query (...

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте такой запрос:

```
$result = mysql_query ("INSERT INTO `$db_table` (`user_mail`) VALUES ('$user_mail');");
```

Ещё помогает сделать запрос в phpMyAdmin(или кто чем пользуется) с тестовыми параметрами( в Вашем случае email). SQL подскажет где ошибка в запросе